# Change functionality of back button

Tags: java, android, back-button

I have a recyclerView in a fragment which I use it to show some items. When selecting these items I change my toolbar title to number of selected items and also I change menu options. how can I make pressing back button cancel the selection operation?

Answer (score 0):

You override the

```
onBackPressed()
```

Method and do what you want there. Any back key press will trigger this function and you'll be able to use your logic